# download a complete folder

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

in my app I use several png-graphics. For the present version they are installed with the app in the folder "graphic". I made while programming. Now I need some more png-graphics and I don't want to make each time an app-update. How can I manage it, that the app is downloading the png-files from my webserver without knowing the name. I am looking for something which compares the files on the webserver with the files on the iPhone and if there is a new (or newer) file download it. Or is it possible to make an plist-file with the graphics??

Comment: what happens while they're downloading the image if they need to view something with the image in it? What happens if they don't have a connection to the internet? What happens if they're only connected to EDGE/3G instead of wireless?

Answer (score 0):

If you enabled directory listing, you could parse the listing and download all files in there.

Comment: don't forget to check checksums or last modified date and filesize to see if they actually need to download it.